# "Unpermitted Parameters" using nested attributes and a has_one :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the Papercrop gem to crop my thumbnail image. It works fine elsewhere on my User Controller however I'm trying to crop with a has_one :through relationship and the nested form isn't playing ball.

Some example parameters:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"t3BsHf6nxAhM9zcRUJfy3nMoLVQAJF/KLbWwqrxeYuk=", "project"=>{"uploaded_image_original_w"=>"960.0", "uploaded_image_original_h"=>"640.0", "uploaded_image_box_w"=>"500", "uploaded_image_crop_x"=>"330", "uploaded_image_crop_y"=>"0", "uploaded_image_crop_w"=>"607", "uploaded_image_crop_h"=>"607", "uploaded_image_aspect"=>"1.0"}, "commit"=>"Save", "profile_name"=>"Benji", "id"=>"1"}
```

And the Error that comes with it:

```
Unpermitted parameters: uploaded_image_original_w, uploaded_image_original_h, uploaded_image_box_w, uploaded_image_crop_x, uploaded_image_crop_y, uploaded_image_crop_w, uploaded_image_crop_h, uploaded_image_aspect
```

Project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_one :thumbnail, :dependent => :destroy
    has_one :image, through: :thumbnail
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :image
end
```

projects_controller.rb (The image_attribute attr_accessors are done by the Papercrop gem)

```
def crop_params
    params.require(:project).permit(image_attributes: [:uploaded_image_original_w, :uploaded_image_original_h, 
                                                     :uploaded_image_box_w, :uploaded_image_crop_x,
                                                     :uploaded_image_crop_y, :uploaded_image_crop_w, 
                                                     :uploaded_image_crop_h, :uploaded_image_aspect])
end
```

Why isn't it permitting these attributes?

edit:

Adding fields_for around changed my error, now the only unpermitted parameter is "image"

```
<%= form_for(@project.thumbnail.image, :as => :project,:url => project_thumbnail_path(@user, @project)) do |f| %>
    <%= f.fields_for :image, @project.thumbnail.image do |pf| %>
        <%= pf.cropbox :uploaded_image, :width => 500 %>
    <%= pf.crop_preview :uploaded_image, :width => 150 %>
    <%= pf.submit 'Save' %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your params, you're not passing `image_attributes:` as a param:

```
"project"=>{"uploaded_image_original_w"=>"960.0", "uploaded_image_original_h"=>"640.0", "uploaded_image_box_w"=>"500", "uploaded_image_crop_x"=>"330", "uploaded_image_crop_y"=>"0", "uploaded_image_crop_w"=>"607", "uploaded_image_crop_h"=>"607", "uploaded_image_aspect"=>"1.0"}
```

You're probably not setting `f.fields_for` in your view (and just using the elements as is instead). Do you have your form code available?

---

To get the above params working, you'll need these `strong_params`:

```
params.require(:project).permit(:uploaded_image_original_w, :uploaded_image_original_h, 
                                                     :uploaded_image_box_w, :uploaded_image_crop_x,
                                                     :uploaded_image_crop_y, :uploaded_image_crop_w, 
                                                     :uploaded_image_crop_h, :uploaded_image_aspect)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. Here's my form -    `<%= form_for(@project.thumbnail.image, :as => :project,:url => project_thumbnail_path(@user, @project)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.cropbox :uploaded_image, :width => 500 %>
  <%= f.crop_preview :uploaded_image, :width => 150 %>
  <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>`    I think need to keep the strong_params inside that because the attr_accessors are in the image model.

Comment: Also I tried wrapping the fields in a fields_for tag gives me an undefined method for nil:NilClass error, because its not referencing the attachment anymore I think.

Comment: Yep, `f.fields_for` requires to you build the nested object before trying to use. Try putting @project.thumbnail.image.build into your `new` method -- I will have a better look in a minute after fixing some things

Comment: There's a thumbnail built already, this is part of an update method & thanks whenever you get an opportunity, I've been going round in circles!

Comment: I've tried this, however I get unpermitted parameter 'image' instead:        `<%= form_for(@project.thumbnail.image, :as => :project,:url => project_thumbnail_path(@user, @project)) do |f| %>
 <%= f.fields_for :image, @project.thumbnail.image do |pf| %>
    <%= pf.cropbox :uploaded_image, :width => 500 %>
    <%= pf.crop_preview :uploaded_image, :width => 150 %>
    <%= pf.submit 'Save' %>
 <% end %>
<% end %>`